# Confusion in int conversion of a string in PHP

Tags: php, integer

I am unable to get the exact value of $data, which I converted into integer from this,

```
<?php

$data = '9999999999';
echo $datan = (int) $data;

?>
```

How can I get the exact value of **$data** from **$datan**?

Comment: I am getting 2147483647, and not 9999999999

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to integer? Most of the time you can work with string numbers in PHP just as well as with pure integers (whether that's a good or bad thing is debatable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the PHP docs:

> The size of an integer is platform-dependent, although a maximum value of about two billion is the usual value (that's 32 bits signed). 64-bit platforms usually have a maximum value of about 9E18. PHP does not support unsigned integers. Integer size can be determined using the constant PHP_INT_SIZE, and maximum value using the constant PHP_INT_MAX since PHP 4.4.0 and PHP 5.0.5.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 0):

Check the `PHP_INT_MAX` of your system.

If you get `2147483647`, it means `PHP_INT_MAX` is `2147483647` in your system(32 bits signed).

Answer (score 0):

Check you `PHP_INT_MAX`. it may be lower than `9999999999`